# HTTP Body with DELETE method is allowed?

Tags: django-rest-framework, http-method

I made API server with Django rest framework.

It is quite simple board, But I have some question about delete article.

When delete article, METHOD will be `DELETE`.

In previous code, I receive parameter(ex. password) to HTTP Body, and it works perfectly.

But after I inspect about this, DELETE Method with HTTP body is not a standard.

So, delete method with http body is bad havior?

Is there any solution about this?

Comment: The id of the deleted article should be passed in the `url`, retrieve it (id) from the delete `view` and delete the article.

Comment: @YusefBH Already article id passed by url. But, article should delete when passed password == database's password. So I have to passed password to my server. My question is `Passed parameter to http body with delete method` is correct way?

Comment: No, is not  the standard way of doing it, you should authenticate the user first, if it's not authenticated he can not delete articles.

Comment: @YusefBH There is no authenticate system. Because it is anonymout board so user do not have to login, just write the article with password.

Comment: Ok. You can use the HTTP `Authorization` request header with the `credentials`, and make sure to use it over `HTTPS` otherwise, credentials are sent in clear text over the network.